# Visual Studio 2013 JavaScript/TypeScript odd indenting behavior

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, typescript

When working on my TypeScript code there is an issue with the automatic indenting of code. I use VS2013 with Resharper.

The problem occurs mostly from method chaining.

For example using promises:

```
someService.GetSomeProperties().then(x => {
    return otherService.doSomethingWithX(x.map(y => y.id));
}).then(x => {
    // Pressing enter sets the cursor to this position
        // Using document format (CTRL+K,CTRL+D) the code moves to this level
        return '';
}).then(x => { // Pressing enter from here
    // Moves the previous line to it's position and cursor here
    return 'a';
    }).then(x => {
        // However document format moves this code block to this indention level
        // as well
    }).then(x => {
        // Follow up chaining remains the same
    });
```

Based on the 'symptoms' this behavior seems to be coming from having multi-line statements in general.

I've looked through both VS2013's options and R#s but I can't find any option that has any effect on this behavior.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: I suggest [filing a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know how to fix it?

It is fixed if you put `then` in a new line (i.e. each top level function gets its own line) and always use semicolons:

```
someService.GetSomeProperties()
    .then(x => {
        return otherService.doSomethingWithX(x.map(y => y.id));
    })
    .then(x => {
        // Pressing enter sets the cursor to this position
        // Using document format (CTRL+K,CTRL+D) the code moves to this level
        return '';
    })
    .then(x => { // Pressing enter from here
        // Moves the previous line to it's position and cursor here
        return 'a';
    })
    .then(x => {
        // However document format moves this code block to this indention level
        // as well
    })
    .then(x => {
        // Follow up chaining remains the same
    });
```

Comment: How is this an answer to my question? Who recommends this style? AFAIK style is a matter of preference, I agree on the semicolons (and am wondering where you see any missing ones), but the `then` on a new line is is the same as people arguing whether you should write an else statement as `} else {` or with a newline `}` \n `else {`.

Comment: Semicolons are not just style, they can _influence behavior_, if they were solely used for aesthetic purposes I couldn't care less which one someone uses, as long as they're consistent about it. For example in Lua they're purely a matter of style, and can always be replaced with a space (except of course in string literals). `.then` on the other hand is unaffected whether you put it on the same line or the next one, so that's just style.

Comment: I agree with @Aidiakapi. Semicolons are widely considered "mandatory" *even if in theory* mostly optional. Putting `then` on a new line certainly is a matter of style, but if switching IDE is not an option, I'd prefer this over broken formatting – at least it's consistent and makes sense (unlike broken indentation).